# Are mapping cones in the bounded homotopy category of chain complexes isomorphic?

Tags: homological-algebra, triangulated-categories, chain-complexes

Let $A$ be an additive category. Suppose we have distinguished triangles
$$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z \rightarrow X[1]$$
and
$$X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow Z' \rightarrow X[1]$$
in the bounded homotopy category $K^b(A)$ of chain complexes. Are the mapping cones $Z$ and $Z'$ isomorphic in $K^b(A)$?

I feel like this is a fairly elementary question, but I am fairly new to homological algebra, so if they are isomorphic, then why?

Comment: This is a basic property of any triangulated category. See for example Remark 1.1.21 in Neeman's book on "Triangulated categories".